# Mapper: if/otherwise

Tags: biztalk

why the mapper doesn't want to make the otherwise-query in the xslt-Dokument?

it should be:
if the script-functoid returns "true" --> it should copy the value from "PV1_19"-Segment in the "MRG_5"-Segment.
otherweise it should copied the MRG1-Segment from the left side to the right side --> i.e. if the MRG_1-Sement from the left side exists, then copy it; if not, it shouldn't exists a MRG-Segment in the Message.

This image shows how i maked it:

[image]

And this is the xslt-Code from the mapper:

```
- <xsl:for-each select="ZBE_BewegungsdatenSegment">
  <xsl:variable name="var:v6" select="userCSharp:ChangeEventToA42(string(ZBE_5_SAPEVENT/text()) , string(ZBE_6_FAL_CASEPATNO/text()) , string(../MSH_MessageHeaderSegment/MSH.9_MessageType/CM_MSG.1_TriggerEvent/text()))" /> 
  <xsl:variable name="var:v7" select="userCSharp:StringConcat("A42")" /> 
  <xsl:variable name="var:v8" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string($var:v6) , string($var:v7))" /> 
- <xsl:if test="$var:v8">
      <xsl:variable name="var:v9" select="string(ZBE_5_SAPEVENT/text())" /> 
      <xsl:variable name="var:v10" select="string(ZBE_6_FAL_CASEPATNO/text())" /> 
      <xsl:variable name="var:v11" select="string(../MSH_MessageHeaderSegment/MSH.9_MessageType/CM_MSG.1_TriggerEvent/text())" /> 
    - <MRG_MergePatientInformation>
        - <MRG_1_PriorPatientIdentifierList>
              <xsl:variable name="var:v12" select="userCSharp:ChangeEventToA42($var:v9 , $var:v10 , $var:v11)" /> 
              <xsl:variable name="var:v13" select="userCSharp:LogicalNe(string($var:v7) , string($var:v12))" /> 
            - <xsl:if test="string($var:v13)='true'">
                  <xsl:variable name="var:v14" select="../MRG_MergePatientInformation/MRG_1_PriorPatientIdentifierList/CX_0_Id/text()" /> 
                - <CX_0_Id>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$var:v14" /> 
                  </CX_0_Id>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:variable name="var:v15" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string($var:v12) , string($var:v7))" /> 
            - <xsl:if test="string($var:v15)='true'">
                  <xsl:variable name="var:v16" select="""" /> 
                - <CX_0_Id>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$var:v16" /> 
                  </CX_0_Id>
              </xsl:if>
          </MRG_1_PriorPatientIdentifierList>
        - <MRG_2_PriorAlternatePatientId>
              <xsl:variable name="var:v17" select="userCSharp:ChangeEventToA42($var:v9 , $var:v10 , $var:v11)" /> 
              <xsl:variable name="var:v18" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string($var:v17) , string($var:v7))" /> 
            - <xsl:if test="string($var:v18)='true'">
                  <xsl:variable name="var:v19" select="""" /> 
                - <CX_0_Id>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$var:v19" /> 
                  </CX_0_Id>
              </xsl:if>
          </MRG_2_PriorAlternatePatientId>
        - <MRG_3_PriorPatientAccountNumber>
              <xsl:variable name="var:v20" select="userCSharp:ChangeEventToA42($var:v9 , $var:v10 , $var:v11)" /> 
              <xsl:variable name="var:v21" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string($var:v20) , string($var:v7))" /> 
            - <xsl:if test="string($var:v21)='true'">
                  <xsl:variable name="var:v22" select="""" /> 
                - <CX_0_Id>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$var:v22" /> 
                  </CX_0_Id>
              </xsl:if>
          </MRG_3_PriorPatientAccountNumber>
        - <MRG_4_PriorPatientId>
              <xsl:variable name="var:v23" select="userCSharp:ChangeEventToA42($var:v9 , $var:v10 , $var:v11)" /> 
              <xsl:variable name="var:v24" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string($var:v23) , string($var:v7))" /> 
            - <xsl:if test="string($var:v24)='true'">
                  <xsl:variable name="var:v25" select="""" /> 
                - <CX_0_Id>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$var:v25" /> 
                  </CX_0_Id>
              </xsl:if>
          </MRG_4_PriorPatientId>
        - <MRG_5_PriorVisitNumber>
              <xsl:variable name="var:v26" select="userCSharp:ChangeEventToA42($var:v9 , $var:v10 , $var:v11)" /> 
              <xsl:variable name="var:v27" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string($var:v26) , string($var:v7))" /> 
            - <xsl:if test="string($var:v27)='true'">
                  <xsl:variable name="var:v28" select="../PV1_PatientVisitSegment/PV1_19_VisitNumber/CX_0_Id/text()" /> 
                - <CX_0_Id>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$var:v28" /> 
                  </CX_0_Id>
              </xsl:if>
          </MRG_5_PriorVisitNumber>
      </MRG_MergePatientInformation>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

do you know why the Mapper dosn't make a "otherwise-query" ( if (yes) and if( not(yes) ) )?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the visual mapper does not work well for complicated mappings.
I switch to an external xslt mapping for anything very complicated.

Comment: Thanks, i know, but I would still use the visual mapper.
I rewrote my intention and it works fine now. But it's realy buggy :)